# tensorflow one to one rnn sequence training

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm using tensorflow

and in the bidirectional part I hope to implement a sound analysis and all the examples i see are from sequence to one kind. And I want a one to one kind of network.

In sequence to one there is this part

```
def BiRNN(x, weights, biases):
    #...some code... 
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']  

pred = BiRNN(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

but I want a one to one like this:

```
def BiRNN(x, weights, biases):
    #...some code... 
    for re in range(n_steps):
        outputs[re] = tf.matmul(outputs[re], weights['out']) + biases['out']
    outputs=tf.pack(outputs)
    return[outputs]

pred = BiRNN(x, weights, biases)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(pred - y, 2))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

but I'm not sure its the right way to do this

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

this can do the trick . msn is a random number between 0 and n_steps

```
outputs=tf.pack(outputs)
    print(outputs)
    outputs=tf.reshape(outputs,[n_steps,6])

    print(tf.slice(outputs,[msn,0],[1,6]))
    return         [tf.slice(outputs,[msn,0],[1,6])-tf.slice(y,[msn,0],[1,6]),outputs]


pred = BiRNN(x,y, weights, biases,msn)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(pred[0], 2))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```